# Issues with triggering a phone call on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, mobile

I'm trying to trigger a phone call on mobile. The idea is that once the user click on a image, a spinner appears and after 2.5 sec it initiates the phone call via window.location.href

```
jQuery('.call-popup').on('click', function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
       window.location.href = 'tel:123456';
    }, 2500);
});
```

However this doesn't seem to work on mobile devices with Chrome.

But if i do this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
       window.location.href = 'tel:123456';
    }, 2500);
});
```

Then it works... Any ideas how to make that first example work on mobile Chrome?

Comment: You are missing a single quote at the end of `'tel:...` in both snippets. Besides that did you try `jQuery(document).on('click', '.call-popup', function(...` ?

Comment: Those quotes were my mistake while c/p. I tried what you recommended but still..the same issue. It's funny because if i put a link to google or any other web it works...but if i use tel: then it doesn't.